# Django Debug Toolbar shows 404 on panel

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

My Django-Debug-Toolbar results in a Http404 as soon as I click on a Panel like "Requests". I checked my config multiple times but can't find whats wrong.

**Versions:**

- django-debug-toolbar == 1.8
- django == 1.11.1

**settings.py**

```
# DEBUG TOOLBAR

if DEBUG:

    def custom_show_toolbar(request):
        """ Only show the debug toolbar to users with the superuser flag. """
        #return request.user.is_superuser
        if request.is_ajax():
            return False
        return True

    MIDDLEWARE += (
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )
    INSTALLED_APPS += (
        'debug_toolbar',
    )
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1', )
    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
        'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'core.settings.custom_show_toolbar',
        'HIDE_DJANGO_SQL': True,
        'TAG': 'body',
        'SHOW_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT': True,
        'ENABLE_STACKTRACES': True,
    }
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', core_views.home, name='home'),
    #url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    #url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    #url(r'^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

**Screenshot**

[image: django-debug-toolbar 404 error on panel click]

Comment: If I remember correctly, clicking on panels triggers an ajax request to load it. Do you still get the error if you stop returning `False` for ajax requests?

Comment: fixed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is your `custom_show_toolbar` method. You are explicitly disabling the toolbar for ajax requests. Since the debug toolbar loads the panel using ajax requests, you get a 404.

```
def custom_show_toolbar(request):
    ...
    if request.is_ajax():
        return False
    return True
```